# How to print log in swc plugin

Tags: swc

This is my swc plugin repo https://github.com/coder-xiaotian/swc-useclient.
I want to print log for debug. I tried to use tracing, but I still can't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the way, just use println().